How was the first tripod able to discharge red weed?
In the Tom Cruise remake of War of The Worlds (2005), it was stated that the "red weed" spraying from the tripods was blood. I get that, but what about the very first tripod to emerge? It hadn't had a chance to grind up, consume and then poop out humans, so what was its red weed composed of? Was it just alien waste?

The linked (duplicate) question indicates that the blood is fertilising and feeding the weed, rather than being its major component.
